# REDIS HSET setting EXpiration time correctly

Tags: node.js, node-redis

```
redis-cli INFO SERVER
# Server
redis_version:7.0.5
...
```

So in node caching some user data the problem having is that the 'EX' instead of setting as the expiration time in seconds is puting as field have the code as follow:

```
        const resultCached = await redisClient.hset(
            accessToken,
            'user',
            JSON.stringify({
                'username'  : username,
                'passHash'  : passHash,
                'loginToken': accessTokenHash
            }),
            'EX',
            7200
        );
```

command to return all fields of this hash are can see the problem as returns "EX" as a field

```
redis-cli HGETALL '$2a$08$a9dv5bFwxsP0Z0eVUuw9XOOwNq85MvP5XHZbpw1cCgfvjlqeqQs0G'
1) "EX"
2) "7200"
3) "user"
4) "{\"username\":\"xpto1\",\"passHash\":\"$2a$08$MeJDVEAw.JKvuKKlC84gMuy0/dZZ/BOsoZSphxuPJZU.1Ro6W6tA.\",\"loginToken\":\"$2a$08$5Pqd6WDZaw6.D71kbqciA.Bz1USDVzPYGqbnQ4BnQcDhZXwofL6La\"}"
```

Wrong this should't be a field but a config of the expiration of this key/data

```
~$ redis-cli HGET '$2a$08$a9dv5bFwxsP0Z0eVUuw9XOOwNq85MvP5XHZbpw1cCgfvjlqeqQs0G' 'EX'
"7200"
```

correct:

```
$ redis-cli HGET '$2a$08$a9dv5bFwxsP0Z0eVUuw9XOOwNq85MvP5XHZbpw1cCgfvjlqeqQs0G' 'user'
"\"username\":\"xpto1\",\"passHash\":\"$2a$08$MeJDVEAw.JKvuKKlC84gMuy0/dZZ/BOsoZSphxuPJZU.1Ro6W6tA.\",\"loginToken\":\"$2a$08$5Pqd6WDZaw6.D71kbqciA.Bz1USDVzPYGqbnQ4BnQcDhZXwofL6La\"}"
```

my question what is the correct format to recongize as config param ("EX") expiration and not a extra field of this key (note in case of `set` it works well as expected only in `hset` having the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `HSET` then `EX` commands in a single network round trip like this which will optimize things somewhat:

```
await Promise.all([
    redisClient.hSet(accessToken, 'user', JSON.stringify(whatever)),
    redisClient.expire(accessToken, 10)
]);
```

In node-redis v4 and up, this will use Redis pipelining to send both commands to the server in the same round trip. https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/

You can't do this with a single command as there isn't a `HSETEX` or equivalent command.

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate command `expire` works well still would prefer to make in single command if possible.

```
const resultExpire = await redisClient.expire(
                        accessToken,
                        10
                     );
```

Comment: Adding a `HSETEX` type command or an `EX` modifier to `HSET` doesn't appear to be something that's in the plans at this point https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/2905 - some other discussions along these lines from a while back can be found here https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/542